# time dependent kml animation

Tags: kml, google-earth

Having a kml file that uses timespan like this:

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/us_states.kml

Is it possible to animate it automatically in google earth in an endless loop so that the slider does not have to moved all the time? Alternatively, can the animated map be recorded as a movie? Thanks.

Comment: sorry - had to "just cannot submit with title" to title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML allows auto animation and looping for flash using the EMBED or OBJECT tags.

KML and Google Earth offers time-based elements that you can animate but there are no auto-play or loop options that you specify in a KML file. Data in KML and how it is handled in Google Earth is more a dynamic data exploration process as opposed to just playing a movie in a fixed static manner on a web page.

You can, however, create a Tour which is a Google Earth KML extension marked by a [gx:Tour](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtour) element in the KML and script the changing of times from start to end for a given duration. But again, KML does not have the option to auto-play a tour so the user must manually activate the tour to start it.

For more info, see tutorial [Touring in KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring).

Recording a movie is a separate step, and while animating the play, you could record a movie using Google Earth Pro or a video capture app like CamStudio.

- http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/02/google-earth-pro-movie-maker.html
- https://sites.google.com/site/kmltouring/google-earth-tools/record-a-tour

If you want a web-based solution, you may want to experiment with [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml) using kml or time animation within [CesiumJs](https://cesiumjs.org/). The [clock](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Clock.html) in Cesium can be configured to loop (e.g., set clock.clockRange = ClockRange.LOOP_STOP) and Cesium supports KML so it might be possible to create what you want using the Cesium API and a few lines of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, can google map handle timespans in kml